# How to get updated spinbox values - tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a GUI and I'm having a problem, where the old spinbox value is being returned (by the get method). I have set up the spinbox so that it is supposed to print out the value of the spinbox, when it is clicked. The problem, is that, it prints out the value that the spinbox WAS set to.

I tried `update()` and `update_idletasks()`, which didn't fix the problem. I then looked around online and I couldn't find anything, so I came here. Thank you, in advance, for any help.

```py
import tkinter as tk

w = tk.Tk() # New window

sb = tk.Spinbox(w, from_=0, to=10) # New spinbox
sb.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda _:print(sb.get())) # Set the spinbox to print out the value it's on when clicked
sb.pack()
```

I expected the output to be what is in the spinbox but it's whatever was previously in the spinbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `command` argument of the spinbox for that.

```py
import tkinter as tk

w = tk.Tk() # New window
sb = tk.Spinbox(w, from_=0, to=10, command=lambda:print(sb.get()))
sb.pack()
```

That will print the current value not just the last value.